# When is the notation $\forall x,y\in\mathbb Z$ admissible?

Tags: notation

In a cryptographic context, about scalar multiplication for a group $(\mathbb G,\hat+)$, I hesitate between writing
$$\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^2,\;\forall U\in\mathbb G,\;[x+y]U=[x]U\,\hat+\,[y]U$$
and
$$\forall x,y\in\mathbb Z,\;\forall U\in\mathbb G,\;[x+y]U=[x]U\,\hat+\,[y]U$$

When is the latter admissible?

As an aside, is the use of comma in my propositions mandatory, optional, or incorrect?

Comment: $\forall x,y \in Z$ means $\forall x \in Z \ \forall y \in Z$, while $\forall (x,y) \in Z^2$ means "for every ordered pair $(x,y)$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those are fine in any situation I've seen. The former is maybe a little bit unnecessarily formal, since you're never really using the pair as one unit in the predicate.

The commas between pairs of quantifiers, or between quantifiers and statements, are not needed. You can use spaces (either the \, or \; size spaces usually look alright for this). Not using any separator at all tends to create a jumbled mess. Also, some people enclose quantifiers in brackets, and may or may not use spaces between them after that.

Of course in publication you will have style rules imposed upon you by the journal or whatever other venue you are publishing in.